# What is domain mapping and how can I do it using cPanel?

Tags: domains, wordpress, dns

I am trying to use the full domain instead of subdomains for a multi-network WordPress site.

When I check the [WordPress documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Multisite_Domain_Mapping), I find the following:

> Make sure all the domains you want to use are already mapped to your
>   DNS server. The additional domains should be parked upon the master
>   domain.

What does it mean? How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Just as for the main/primary domain on your account, you need to configure any additional domains to point to your server. You can do this by either setting `NAMESERVERS` at your domain registrar to point to your *hosts* DNS (or whoever's DNS servers you are using). Or, set an `A` record in the current master DNS records for the additional domain (which maybe at your domain registrar) to point to your application server. By changing the domain's `NAMESERVERS` to your hosts DNS then your host will manage the appropriate `A` records for you (when you configure "Alias" or "Addon" domains in cPanel - next step).

You must then configure your web *host* to accept requests to this additional domain. In cPanel you do this by creating an "Addon" domain or a Domain "Alias" (formerly called a "Parked" domain). If configuring WordPress multisite then you probably want to create a Domain "Alias", which simply maps the additional domain to the root of your account - essentially mirroring the main domain (WordPress then controls which site to display for the requested domain). An "Addon" domain generally points to a subdirectory (or rather, a *subdomain*) off your main account - which is more appropriate for creating entirely separate sites.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. I just didn't answer the following part. "_If configuring WordPress multisite then **you probably want to create a Domain "Alias", which simply maps the additional domain to the root of your account** - essentially mirroring the main domain (WordPress then controls which site to display for the requested domain _"

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure that I follow... are you saying that that was really the only thing that was missing from your understanding?

Comment: Yes. What I understood was I need to add all domains as add-on domains in cPanel and all domains should be set to the root(I setup mutisite in root.) I didn't understand that **create a Domain "Alias"** part.